# Screen reader is not reading the state of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accessibility

I have this html:

https://codepen.io/erperejildo/pen/KKGjWMN

By jquery, when I click on this div I add/remove `.selected` (just adding a green background) and I change the value of `aria-selected`.

Using this screen reader: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-reader/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn/related
when I click on the label, it says: "My element. Button is selected". Which is correct.
But when I click AGAIN on the image: "My element. Button is selected". The class and the aria-selected are changed correctly, but what it reads is not correct because this time it's unselected. It always says the wrong state when the image is clicked.

Also, when trying this with other native screen readers on the phone, it doesn't even say anything (like in the example link I posted).

I can click the container or any of the child elements, but it should always read the main container state. Right now it's just an image, but the content of `.container` is open to the users and they can add custom elements to it, so it should always work in the same way, regardless how many children `.container` has.

I can also change the structure and instead of a button have something else, but the final result should be a clickable box with several elements inside. Clicking inside, it should say if it's activated/enabled/pressed or something similar.

Comment: giving aria-label to img tag might solve your problem.

Comment: Could you please try to provide an interactive code example in your question, which makes reproducing your issue way easier. I see some issues with your code, though: `<label>` is useless inside a button. [Labels provide an accessible name to form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), which is not the case here. Do you bind a `keydown` event on that div, too? It needs to work with keyboard as well.

Comment: @Erenn if I add the aria-label to the image it reads that label when the image is clicked. But it doesn't change anything. I want to know if the main div is selected or not and that not working

Comment: @Andy please check the link I added

Comment: they keyboard part is shorted. The problem is just related with the screen reader

Comment: Keyboard control is the foundation for screen reader accessibility.

Comment: you can tab and select all elements by keyboard, the problem is just with this as I mentioned

Comment: Actually, [`aria-selected` is not supported for buttons](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#button), so screen reader behaviour will be unpredictable. Did you try `aria-pressed` instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253900/discussion-between-andy-and-dani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *button* together with states like `checked`, or `pressed` is apparently not very well supported. [`aria-selected` is not a valid attribute for `button`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#button).

The [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG) suggest a Switch](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/switch/examples/switch-button/), which seems to be better supported.

> A `switch` provides approximately the same functionality as a checkbox and toggle button, but makes it possible for assistive technologies to present the widget in a fashion consistent with its on-screen appearance.

So you would use [the `switch` role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#desc-switch) together with its `aria-checked` state.

Give it a try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").click(function(e) {
    $(".container").toggleClass("selected");
    $(".container").attr("aria-checked", $(".container").hasClass("selected"));
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" role="switch" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false">
  <img width="200" height="150" src="https://www.renovablesverdes.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/dia-del-arbol.jpg" alt="" aria-hidden="true" /> My element
</div>
```

As you might notice in the above quote, the current visual appearance is not that of a switch, so you might pose some usability issues in that regard.

The Chrome screen reader extension is known to lack support of big parts of ARIA, so it would be better to test with a more [popular screen reader](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#primary), like NVDA, which is free.

---

In the JavaScript code, I recommend to bind the ARIA attribute value directly to the `selected` class, otherwise the logic is sensitive to side effects, like another script changing the class but not the ARIA attribute.

Even better would be to bind the CSS to the ARIA attribute: `.container[aria-checked="true"] {`.

Comment: I'll try to get access to any of those popular screen readers because the one I'm using doesn't work at all with this change. It seems better approach TBH so I'll implement it and try at least with native voiceover from iOS. Thanks!